# How to fix x-axis names?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
a<-data.frame(time=c("before","after","before","after"),
                  company=c(1,1,2,2),
                  value=c(3.751522,4.776224,3.838707,2.644144 ))
```

And to plot a graph I used the following code

```
a$company<-as.factor(a$company)
ggplot(a, aes(x=company, y=value, fill=time)) + geom_col(position="dodge")
```

As a result, I have the figure for two companies with after and before bars. However, how to fix a problem that the first bar of the company corresponds to the before and next to the after, and not vica versa as in my graph?

Answer (score 2):

Does this achieve what you want:

```
a<-data.frame(time=factor(c("before","after","before","after"),
                          levels = c("before", "after")),
              company=c(1,1,2,2),
              value=c(3.751522,4.776224,3.838707,2.644144 ))
a$company<-as.factor(a$company)
ggplot(a, aes(x=company, y=value, fill=time)) + geom_col(position="dodge")
```

Comment: Agree with this. I might even use `ordered()` instead of `factor()` on the time column.

Comment: Thanks, it is working